# The context `router.history` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, tabs, react-router

During building a Tabs in my react application I got stack on an error

```
 warning.js:33 Warning: Failed context type: The context 
   `router.history` is marked as required in `Link`, but 
  its value is `undefined`.
in Link (created by ChatIndexContainer)
in li (created by ChatIndexContainer)
in ul (created by ChatIndexContainer)
in div (created by ChatIndexContainer)
in div (created by ChatIndexContainer)
in ChatIndexContainer (created by Connect(ChatIndexContainer))
in Connect(ChatIndexContainer) (created by RouterContext)
in RouterContext (created by Router)
in Router (created by App)
in App
in Provider
```

As far as I find cause this problem is version of `react-router`. I am using `"react-router": "~3.2.0"` and `"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"` but I have to use at least 4.0.0. After I update it whole my react app crashed. Are there any other solutions to solve this error and stay with current `react-router` version?

Here is component that create this error:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as chatActions from '../actions/chats';
import MessageTile from '../components/MessageTile';

 class ChatIndexContainer extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
   }

   render() {
    return(
      <div>
       <div className="links">
        <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`/chats`}></Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div className="tabs">
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`/chats/:chatId`} component={MessageTile} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
 }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
   chats: state.chats
  }),
  chatActions
)(ChatIndexContainer);
```

Comment: have you used BrowserRouter of HAshRouter somewhere in your app

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri no I didn't use any of these in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Your Link and Route components must be present within the BrowserRouter, HashRouter or Router provided with a Custom history components

```
class ChatIndexContainer extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
   }

   render() {
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
           <div>
               <div className="links">
                <ul>
                <li>
                  <Link to={`/chats`}></Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="tabs">
              <Switch>
                <Route path={`/chats/:chatId`} component={MessageTile} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>  
      )
   }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
   chats: state.chats
  }),
  chatActions
)(ChatIndexContainer);
```